# How to retrieve data between dates(Fromdate, Todate) when Todate is null? query should continue from 'Fromdate' to next dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-date-functions

```
create proc splist_of_current_orders (@fromdate nvarchar(50),@todate nvarchar(50) )
as
begin
    SELECT 
        ot.Order_Id, 
        ot.Pay_date, 
        ot.Pay_type, 
        ot.Merchant_Id, 
        t.BusinessName, 
        t.OyospaName, 
        tu.Userfullname, 
        ot.Booked_Date
    FROM dbo.Tbl_Order_Trans AS ot 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.Tbl_ServiceCategory AS sc ON sc.ServiceCategoryID = ot.ServiceCategoryID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.Tbl_user AS tu ON ot.UserId = tu.UserId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.Tbl_Merchant AS t ON ot.Merchant_Id = t.Merchant_Id 

    where ot.Booking_Date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate
end
```

Answer (score 0):

may be do like this

```
create proc splist_of_current_orders (@fromdate datetime,@todate datetime )
as
begin
SELECT ot.Order_Id, ot.Pay_date, ot.Pay_type, ot.Merchant_Id, t.BusinessName, t.OyospaName, tu.Userfullname, ot.Booked_Date
FROM            dbo.Tbl_Order_Trans AS ot LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Tbl_ServiceCategory AS sc ON sc.ServiceCategoryID = ot.ServiceCategoryID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Tbl_user AS tu ON ot.UserId = tu.UserId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Tbl_Merchant AS t ON ot.Merchant_Id = t.Merchant_Id where convert(date,ot.Booking_Date) BETWEEN convert(date,@fromdate) and convert(date,@todate)
                         end
```